# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-redux'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting errors as specified below. i don't know where i am going wrong.please help me out.
I have changed my webpack config also and i have also updated react-hot-webpack loader also but still i am getting these errors..

Thanks in advance.

these are the errors i am getting.

```
ERROR in ./~/redux-form/lib/reduxForm.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-redux' in /home/priyanka/Finalproject/node_modules/redux-form/lib
 @ ./~/redux-form/lib/reduxForm.js 27:18-40

ERROR in ./~/redux-form/lib/values.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-redux' in /home/priyanka/Finalproject/node_modules/redux-form/lib
 @ ./~/redux-form/lib/values.js 9:18-40

ERROR in ./~/redux-form/lib/ConnectedField.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-redux' in /home/priyanka/Finalproject/node_modules/redux-form/lib
 @ ./~/redux-form/lib/ConnectedField.js 13:18-40
```

this is my react code

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
const reducers = {
  // ... your other reducers here ...
  form: formReducer     // <---- Mounted at 'form'
}
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers)
const store = createStore(reducer)


class ContactForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <Field name="firstName" component={React.DOM.input} type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <Field name="lastName" component={React.DOM.input} type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <Field name="email" component={React.DOM.input} type="email"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

// Decorate the form component
ContactForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'contact' // a unique name for this form
})(ContactForm);

export default ContactForm;
```

and this is my webpack

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
{ test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' },

      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules|lib\/ckeditor)/
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
       loaders: ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader']
     }


    ]
  },
  resolve: {
  alias: { 'react/lib/ReactMount': 'react-dom/lib/ReactMount' }
}
};
```

Comment: How does your package.json look like? Did you add the 'react-redux' dependency?

Comment: Ya i have just installed only redux..now i have installed react-redux..thank you..but what's the difference??

Comment: react-redux gives you access to the Provider and Connect components as well as the ability to map redux state to props and action creators to dispatch. These components mean that you can connect some of your React components to the Redux store. Since these are react components the author decided that they should be in their own library and not in the redux library.

Comment: I have another error in my code as                                                                                                                                     Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Form(Createstudent))". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Form(Createstudent))".  How do i fix this error?

Answer (score 8):

```
npm install react-redux  --save
```

This should solve the issue

Answer (score 3):

I think you haven't installed 'react-redux' package. make sure it is in your package.json file. and if it is not present there please install it using '`npm install --save react-redux`'

Answer (score 0):

So I encountered this problem trying to integrate `redux-form` to [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate).

This can be related to the situation when you try to use `redux-form` with the `Redux` store configured to use `ImmutableJS` objects.

Please, refer to the [docs](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.14/examples/immutable/). Since versions 6 this is officially supported.

**TL;DR**

1) you must have special imports:

```
// reducer registration:
import formReducer from 'redux-form/immutable';

// form implementation:
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable' // <--- immutable import
```

2) you should keep in mind non-standard objects nature while implementing validation:

```
const validate = values => {
  // IMPORTANT: values is an Immutable.Map here!
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.get('username')) {
    errors.username = 'Required'
  }
  return errors;
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me by running these two commands

```
npm install react-redux  --save
```

then have to run second command

```
npm install --save redux-form
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `"@reduxjs/toolkit"`. and you are getting this error.

Then no need to add the `redux` to the `packages.json`.

Just you need these `"@reduxjs/toolkit"` and `"react-redux"`.

To resolve the issue, delete all the folders from `node_modules` and do a `npm i`.

It will resolve the things.

Sample `package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.9.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0"
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

This solved the issue for me.

```
npm install --save redux-form
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider formatting your code with backticks ``